# Opening scripter in Whitebox GAT?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, whitebox-gat

I am trying to open the scripter or scripting tool in Whitebox GAT so that I can edit Export GeoTIFF tool to make Whitebox export a TIFF file from dep/tas format, which was suggested by Whitebox developer in [another post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208404/exporting-a-whitebox-gat-raster-to-geotiff-format). But nothing pops up when click the tool. I am in Windows 10 and I have Java the newest version.

Comment: Please provide a link to the earlier post that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The WhiteBox-GAT scripter icon, which looks like an unrolled scroll, can be found  at the toolbar next to Raster Calculator.

[image]

However, I prefer to export the raster as a SAGA Grid (.sdat). (`Data Import/Export > Export SAGA Grid`)

SAGA Grid can be read by various GIS software (e.g. QGIS, SAGA), thanks to GDAL.

Comment: thanks. I know where the tool icon is, but my problem is when I click it, nothing pops up to allow me to edit the script.

Comment: @JJHan That's interesting. Can you edit your question to add your environment?